# git pull from default branch (main or master) for each git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

My git repository has many submodules and some submodules' default branches are `main` and others are `master`.

I would like to pull from remote default branches using a command without error.
If all submodules are using `main` or `master`, these commands works.

> $ git submodule for each git pull origin master

or

> $ git submodule for each git pull origin main

But,  if mixed, I don't know how to do it.
Does anyone know a good solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+update

Comment: `git submodule update --recursive --remote`